# Min/max fill for coolant reserve/overflow tank in abscence of markings

Tags: honda, coolant, cooling-system, prelude

I have a 2001 Honda Prelude SH. I am looking at the coolant reserve tank. There are no min / max fill lines visible, although the manual says there should be.

I am just re-adding coolant after fixing a leak.

Is there a rule of thumb for rough min / max levels in the reserve tank if there aren't any clear markings? Or does anybody know what it should be specifically for this car?

I can't really remove the tank easily to look for markings, and I didn't see anything in pictures of the tanks on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a picture of your coolant recovery tank:

[image]

If you look on the right side of it, you'll see the two lines there on the outside. Those are your min/max lines. Hopefully you can align this with what is in your vehicle to get a good understanding of where it should be.

Comment: Great thanks, I can see them now, looking down inside the tank. I had been looking for something with clearer labels. Are raised ridges like that pretty typical in other vehicles too?

Comment: @JasonC - Very typical.